# resizing images in python not actually resizing

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy

I'm reading in an image and using `skimage.transform` to resize it. But when I print out the dimensions, the image still has the same size. I can also see by just using `io.imshow()` that the size hasn't changed.

I want to resize it to have width: 60, and height: 30.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, io, filter, color, exposure
from skimage.transform import resize, rescale, rotate, setup, warp, AffineTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(path+readfile))
resize(img, (30,60))
print img.shape
io.imshow(img)
io.show()
```

What's missing in this code?

Comment: `reshaped=resize(img, (30,60))`  `io.imshow(reshaped)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resize returns the changed image. Try this?

```
new_img = resize(img, (30,60))
print new_img.shape
```